# Redirect video resource on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect, video-streaming, cgi

I have a Tomcat 10 server with my java application and I have an IP camera with a html cgi video resource to view the stream.
This camera has a standard Digest Auth and I want to embedd its video stream to my html page. I don't want to make user insert camera credential, and of course I cannot include credentials in my page. User has an active session ID managed on my Tomcat, so is there a way to combine all to make video stream visible on html page, where user has an active session, through Tomcat and managing camera auth via server?

I tried to figure out if I have to use proxy or redirecting, or maybe some tunneling.